# FSharp ProvidedConstructor Arguments

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm trying to implement a typeprovider using the examples I found in different places.

What I want is to be able to create a constructor which assigns the provided arguments to the right properties. The result will have do the same thing as the type below.

```
type SomeType(arg1: int, arg2: string) = 
    member this.Arg1 = arg1
    member this.Arg2 = arg2
```

I've tried different approaches, but I just can't get passed the first argument in the args list.

```
ProvidedConstructor(
    parameters = parameters, 
    InvokeCode = (fun args -> ??)
```

What kind of code must be invoked to achieve this. Or do I have to take another approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What will be the underlying runtime representation of your provided type (the type you passed to the `ProvidedTypeDefinition` `baseType` argument)? The `ProvidedConstructor` `InvokeCode` is a function that takes a list of expressions and returns an expression of the underlying type. For example, if the runtime representation is a 2-element tuple, `InvokeCode` would be something like this:

```
InvokeCode = (fun [arg1;arg2] -> <@@ (%%arg1:int), (%%arg2:string) @@>)
```

Make sure to read [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh361034.aspx)

Comment: Hi Gustavo, Thanks for your reply. What wasn't clear to me is that the Expr returns the underlying type.